# Как достать адрес изображения из HTML средствами библиотеки JSOUP?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Есть разметка сайта

```
<span class="b-poster-tile__image">
    <span class="b-poster-tile__image-fsua-mark">.UA</span>
    <span class="b-poster-tile__image-fsto-mark">.TO</span>
    <img src="http://img.dotua.org/fsua_items/cover/00/41/31/6/00413106.jpg"
         alt="Ворошилов против Тухачевского. Маршал на заклание"
         width="140" height="{(($params['html_class'] == 'b-poster-music') || ($params['html_class'] == 'b-poster-clip')) ? '140' : '205'}">
</span>
```

как мне вытащить путь к изображению `http://img.dotua.org/fsua_items/cover/00/41/31/6/00413106.jpg`

Остальное вытягиваю вот так

```
@Override
protected List<ClassDataBuilder> doInBackground(List<ClassDataBuilder>... params) {
    Document docTxt;
    List<ClassDataBuilder> classDataBuilder = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        docTxt = Jsoup.connect("http://fs.to/video/films/?sort=popularity").get();
        titleTxt = docTxt.select(".b-poster-tile__title-full");
        titleList.clear();

        for (Element contents : titleTxt) {
            titleList.add(contents.text());
            Log.d("TITLE", contents.text());
        } ...\\\
```

На выходи имею массив строк с нужными данными.
 А в случаи с картинкой что делать?

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Адрес изображения в теге `img` указывается в аттрибуте с именем `src`. Засим вам надо было гуглить

> [jsoup get attr](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jsoup%20get%20attr)

чтобы получить ответ:

```
String imageUrl = contents.attr("src");
```

---

Не знаю, что у вас не получилось с foreach... Должно быть как-то так, судя по вашему комменту:

```
Elements imgTags = docTxt.select("img");
//или
//Elements imgTags = docTxt.getElementsByTag("img");
for (Element img : imgTags) 
{
    String url = img.attr("abs:src");
    urlList.add( url ); 
    Log.d("URL", url ); 
}
```

Comment: `for (Element contents : imgUrl) {
                    urlList.add(contents.attr("src"));
                }` не заполняет...точнее заполняет пустой строкой

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександров, в приведённой вами строке нет ошибки. Она где-то в другом месте. Проверьте, что вы правильно заполнили список Elements, что он содержит теги img.

Comment: Разобрался, в `for each` не работает, надо брать поэлементно `for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
                    imgUrl = docTxt.select("img").get(i);
                    urlList.add(imgUrl.attr("abs:src"));
                    Log.d("URL", imgUrl.attr("abs:src"));
                }`

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександров, можно и с `foreach` - см. обновлённый ответ.